# Return a custom card and dismisable from a ListView.builder (add and delete to a list view)

Tags: android, flutter, listview

I want to make a shopping cart in a flutter app, and I want to add cards, delete them using ListView.builder. So I want to return my custom card, and dismisable widget in the same list view, but I don't know how.

This is the code

```
class CartScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CartScreenState createState() => _CartScreenState();
}

class _CartScreenState extends State<CartScreen> {
  List<Product>cartProducts=[];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        actions: [
          IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home_rounded),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, 'homeScreen');
              })
        ],
        title: Text('Cart'),
        flexibleSpace: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              gradient: LinearGradient(
                  begin: Alignment.bottomLeft,
                  end: Alignment.topRight,
                  colors: <Color>[
                kCostumeBlueColor6,
                kCostumeBlueColor5,
              ])),
        ),
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(itemBuilder: (context,index){
   //     return Dismissible(key: key, child: child);

        return CartCard(image: NetworkImage('link'), productName: cartProducts[index].getProductName(), price: cartProducts[index].getPrice(),);

      },

      itemCount: cartProducts.length,)

    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options depending on your constraints:

1. Wrap your CartCard in a Dismissible like

```dart
   return  Dismissible(key: key, child: CartCard(
      image: NetworkImage('link'),
      productName: cartProducts[index].getProductName(),
      price: cartProducts[index].getPrice(),));
```

2. If they are indeed two separate widgets use a Column to make your desired layout

```dart
   return  
Column(children:[
Dismissible(key: key, child: ),
CartCard(
      image: NetworkImage('link'),
      productName: cartProducts[index].getProductName(),
      price: cartProducts[index].getPrice(),)
]);
```

3. If you have few items and do not need a ListView.builder you can use spreads:

```dart
   return  
ListView(children:[
for (final cart in cartProducts)
...[Dismissible(key: key, child: ),
CartCard(
      image: NetworkImage('link'),
      productName: cart.getProductName(),
      price: cart.getPrice(),)]
]);
```